# Firebase parou de salvar no realtime-database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

De ontem para hoje, o firebase parou de salvar qualquer tipo de dado no realtime-database e eu gostaria de saber por que. Eu ontem mesmo estava testando meu app de WhatsApp clone naturalmente, mas sem alterar nada no código, e com as regras dele ainda públicas. Não faço ideia do que fazer e não conseguirei prosseguir meu curso sem ele.

PS: Eu não alterei nada no código em momento nenhum, os dados de usuários cadastrados são automaticamente autenticados pelo servidor, mas nada entra no banco de dados. Ontem mesmo, fora de casa eu até demonstrei a um amigo o funcionamento do app e do banco de dados, e tudo estava salvando perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Implemente a seguinte linha em seu código para receber informações detalhadas das operações do firebase :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

Após isso, execute o código e verifique o logcat, que certamente mostrará o que o firebase estiver fazendo. Se ainda assim tiver dúvidas, adicione o logcat em sua pergunta.